# Java Virtual Machine Launcher error

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbVlh.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxvw6.jpg)Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

I'm getting this error. I'm running one selenium script on my virtual Machine. I tried each method but not helping. Can you please suggest?

Comment: This means the code was compiled for Java 8, you need Java 8+.

Comment: I tried Java 8 also , same error I'm getting

Comment: Nope, you didn't. Run `java -version`, you'll find you're not running Java 8. You may have it installed, but you likely don't have the correct version in your `PATH`.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)